# TypeError: div(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.bool_

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying a model, ODE-Net, on medical images to get some results of segmentation.
While going through the experiment this error appeared: 
`TypeError: div(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.bool_` 
The error is indicated to the **last line** in the below section of the code:

`def apply_data_augmentation(self, image, mask):
        patch = torch.from_numpy(image.transpose(2, 0, 1)).float() / 255
        n_glands = mask.max()
        label = torch.from_numpy(mask).float() / n_glands`

The `mask` is a ground truth of an image.

The above portion is preceded by:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    image, mask = self.index_to_filename(index)
    image, mask = self.open_and_resize(image, mask)
    image, mask = self.pad_image(image, mask)
    label, patch = self.apply_data_augmentation(image, mask)
    label = self.create_eroded_mask(label, mask)
    patch, label = self.extract_random_region(image, patch, label)
    return patch, label.float()

def index_to_filename(self, index):
    """Helper function to retrieve filenames from index"""
    index_img = index // self.repeat
    index_img = self.images[index_img]
    index_str = str(index_img.item() + 1)

    image = self.image_fname + index_str + '.jpg'
    mask = self.image_fname + index_str + '_anno.png'
    return image, mask

def open_and_resize(self, image, mask):
    """Helper function to pad smaller image to the correct size"""
    image = PIL.Image.open(image)
    mask = PIL.Image.open(mask)

    ratio = (775 / 512)
    new_size = (int(round(image.size[0] / ratio)),
                int(round(image.size[1] / ratio)))

    image = image.resize(new_size)
    mask = mask.resize(new_size)

    image = np.array(image)
    mask = np.array(mask)
    return image, mask

def pad_image(self, image, mask):
    """Helper function to pad smaller image to the correct size"""
    if not self.validation:
        pad_h = max(self.patch_size[0] - image.shape[0], 128)
        pad_w = max(self.patch_size[1] - image.shape[1], 128)
    else:
        # we pad more than needed to later do translation augmentation
        pad_h = max((self.patch_size[0] - image.shape[0]) // 2 + 1, 0)
        pad_w = max((self.patch_size[1] - image.shape[1]) // 2 + 1, 0)

    padded_image = np.pad(image, ((pad_h, pad_h), (pad_w, pad_w), (0, 0)), mode='reflect')
    mask = np.pad(mask, ((pad_h, pad_h), (pad_w, pad_w)), mode='reflect')
    return padded_image, mask
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated; thanks in advance!

PS: I'm trying the code on Google Colab.

Comment: Is this your own code?  If so, what's the purpose?  What is `mask`?  Is that an numpy array with `boolean` dtype?  If so, `max` will just be `True/False`, not some sort of count.  It's doesn't make sense to divide by a boolean, does it?

Comment: @hpaulj No, sir! that's not my own code. I have reproduced results from using the code on the data they have tested. Now, I want to try it on different data of that kind.

Comment: @hpaulj Sir, `mask` is a ground truth of an image and above this section of the code it is defined as: `pad_h = max((self.patch_size[0] - image.shape[0]) // 2 + 1, 0)`
            `pad_w = max((self.patch_size[1] - image.shape[1]) // 2 + 1, 0)`

        `padded_image = np.pad(image, ((pad_h, pad_h), (pad_w, pad_w), (0, 0)), mode='reflect')`
             `mask = np.pad(mask, ((pad_h, pad_h), (pad_w, pad_w)), mode='reflect')`

Comment: Code in a comment is hard to read.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, sir! I have included the code in the question. Please, check there, sir.

Comment: So you showed how you 'padded' the `mask` variable, but that still doesn't tell us much about `mask`.  The error suggests that it's a boolean `dtype` array.  When working with `numpy` it's important that you not only understand the `shape` of arrays, but also the `dtype`.

Comment: @hpaulj Sir, updated the question; added the preceded portion of the error, from where the mask starts. Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after initializing mask.

```py
mask = np.array(mask, dtype='float')
```

The method `torch.from_numpy` expects objects of type `float` or `np.float` since every tensor in torch is a `torch.FloatTensor`. 

There are a couple of ways to get around it. One way is to convert boolean array to float using `np.array` with `dtype='float'` 
 OR 
 Declare an empty `torch.BoolTensor` and then use the method `from_numpy`.

PS
`np.array` selects a suitable datatype for the loaded image. For `bool` images it's
`np.bool`.